# htaccess rewrite rule if URL is specific

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am trying this code in my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api\/(.*)?$ /api/$1 [L,QSA]
```

As an example, if the URL visited is `www.domain.com/api/test` i want it to rewrite directly to `www.domain.com/api/test.php`

But its just returning a 500 Internal Server error

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/([^./]+)/?$ api/$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Check your error.log and see what exact error log is showing up there